# no graphics visible on LCD on running qt application

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am trying to cross compile and run a qt application on a arm board which has a LCD connected to it. I used the below code and cross compiled it for arm. Now when I run this application it executes but no graphics is visible on the LCD. Can anybody help me. Do I need to export something.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication app(argc, argv);

   QPushButton hello("Hello world!");

   hello.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done a project "RFID based Authorization System" for which I had to run a qt application on LCD interfaced with Raspberry pi (arm board).

Please provide some more information so that I can be of more help to you.

Make sure you had done:

1. Correct QT package (Qt on ARM embedded system)
2. Every time you port your program from Intel (your computer) to ARM based, you need to configure your project on Qt creator.
3. Make sure graphics environment is enabled on ARM board you are working. By default, command line interface is enabled on ARM board and you need to enable GUI separately.